# What's the best way to deal with Questions that have "Not possible" as an answer?

Tags: discussion

I've asked some "how-to" questions that turned out that I can't do what i'm asking for. I receive that "Not possible" answer in the comments, because there is no actual answer for the question. In this case, is it better to delete the question or is it more beneficial for other users to leave the unanswered question as it is with only the comment ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMO "not possible" is a just fine answer, as long as there is given specific reasoning as to **why**.

The best course of action would be to encourage the commenter to hash out his assessment in an answer, since comments are ephemeral.

Sometimes it's simply the best answer that can be given and it should be treated as such.

If the commenter does not react to this and hasn't given any reasoning: Do some research and answer the question yourself! A question with an answer is often better than a question with no answer, or even a deleted question.

Answer (score 2):

I want to add that sometimes things not possible when the question is asked become possible after some new technology appears or workarounds get invented.

So it is better to leave the question as it is.